# run Java program with jar from Python

Tags: java, python, jar, operating-system, command

I am trying to run a java file with a jar from Python. 
I first run the command :

```
java -classpath ".:/Users/blablalba/jackson-all-1.9.0.jar" parseJason
```

it worked perfectly.
Then I wrote a small python script to execute the java file. (Updated: I made a change based on the suggestion below.

```
import os.path,subprocess
from subprocess import STDOUT,PIPE

def compile_java(java_file):
    subprocess.check_call(['javac', java_file])

def execute_java(java_file, stdin):
    java_class,ext = os.path.splitext(java_file)
   // cmd = ['java', java_class] change to
    cmd = ['java', 
  '-classpath',  '.:/Users/blablalba/jackson-all-1.9.0.jar', 
  'parseJason']
        proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
        stdout,stderr = proc.communicate(stdin)

compile_java('parseJason.java')
execute_java('parseJason.java', 'data.json','output_010.csv')
```

Data.json is the input file name and output_010.csv is the output file name. My java file gets those two parameters through reading the scanner.system.in.

Then I run the command :

```
    python parseJson.py
```

I received the following error:

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
                                ^
parseJason.java:380: error: cannot find symbol
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        ^
  symbol:   class ObjectMapper
  location: class parseJason
parseJason.java:380: error: cannot find symbol
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                                  ^
  symbol:   class ObjectMapper
  location: class parseJason
3 errors
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parseJson.py", line 15, in <module>
    compile_java('parseJason.java')
  File "parseJson.py", line 5, in compile_java
    subprocess.check_call(['javac', java_file])
  File "/Users/***/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 541, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['javac', 'parseJason.java']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Anyone has ideas what I am missing here? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Command '['java', 'parseJason.java']'
```

The command should be the same as before

- the classpath is missing
- the main class is called `parseJason`, not `parseJason.java`

Try

```
cmd = ['java', 
  '-classpath',  '.:/Users/blablalba/jackson-all-1.9.0.jar', 
  'parseJason']
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. May you be more specific about how could I fix my program.Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you! I made some changed based on your suggestion and am receiving a new error.

Comment: You need that classpath also for the `javac` command. But do you really want to compile this every time? Usually, people compile java upfront and deploy just the compiled binaries.

Comment: So you mean, I actually do not need the function "compile_java". I can compile java unfront and just run the "execute_java" function?

Comment: I upgraded to Python 3. when I run my program , I had the following error "memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'"  May you take a look at this post. Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40851622/run-java-from-python-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str